# Python boto3 script loses AWS credentials with minor change

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm listing EC2 instances in a number of different AWS accounts. The regions I need to loop through varies based on the type of the AWS account.

The script works if I use this function:

```
def set_regions(aws_account):
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    regions = []
    gov_regions = ['us-gov-east-1', 'us-gov-west-1']
    alz_regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-west-2']
    managed_aws_accounts = ['company-lab', 'company-bill', 'company-stage', 'company-dlab', 'company-nonprod', 'company-prod', 'company-security-csm', 'company-logging-csm', 'company-lighthouse', 'company-ab-nonprod', 'company-ab-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-admin-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-ab-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-ab-admin-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-admin-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-admin-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-core-qa-admin', 'company-govcloud-ab-core-qa', 'company-govcloud-ab-core-stage-admin', 'company-govcloud-ab-core-stage', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-qa-admin', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-qa', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage-admin', 'company-govcloud-ab-mc-stage', 'company-govcloud-admin-ab-dsg-logmon-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-ab-dsg-logmon-nonprod', 'company-govcloud-admin-ab-dsg-logmon-prod', 'company-govcloud-ab-dsg-logmon-prod', 'company-govcloud-admin-ab-dsg-logmon-nonprod2', 'company-govcloud-ab-dsg-logmon-nonprod2', 'company-govcloud-admin-ab-dsg-logmon-prod2', 'company-govcloud-ab-dsg-logmon-prod2', 'company-ab-sandbox', 'company-govcloud-ab-hipaa-admin-np',  'company-govcloud-ab-hipaa-np', 'company-govcloud-ab-hipaa-admin-pd', 'company-govcloud-ab-hipaa-pd', 'company-ksr-a', 'company-ksr-b', 'company-dsg-logging-admin', 'company-dsg-logging-gov', 'company-dsg-security-admin', 'company-dsg-security-gov', 'company-dsg-security-lab', 'company-adv-gov-test-admin', 'company-adv-gov-test' ]
    if aws_account in managed_aws_accounts:
        if 'gov' in aws_account and not 'admin' in aws_account:
            regions = gov_regions
        else:
            regions = [reg['RegionName'] for reg in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    else:
        regions = alz_regions

    return regions
```

But if I remove just the alz_regions and the managed_aws_accounts from the function like this:

```
def set_regions(aws_account):
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    regions = []
    gov_regions = ['us-gov-east-1', 'us-gov-west-1']

    if 'gov' in aws_account and not 'admin' in aws_account:
        regions = gov_regions
    else:
        regions = [reg['RegionName'] for reg in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    return regions
```

The script can no longer find its AWS credentials:

```
Exception has occurred: NoCredentialsError
Unable to locate credentials
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Company\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_reporting_tools\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 137, in set_regions
    regions = [reg['RegionName'] for reg in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Company\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_reporting_tools\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 701, in main
    regions = set_regions(aws_account)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Company\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_reporting_tools\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 843, in <module>
    main()
```

Why would a minor change like that cause this error?

Comment: Is `describe_regions()` actually called in the working variant? What is the value of `aws-account` in each case?

Comment: It looks like `describe_regions()` isn't getting called in the working version. If `aws_account` is in `managed_aws_accounts` it's supposed to use the `alz_regions` list. However the value of `aws_account` is `cmi-mx-lab` and that dos not correspond to anything in the `managed_aws_accounts` array. Odd!

Comment: I fixed it by setting the session info at the top of the function: `    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2')`. That got it resolved.

Comment: It's not so much that you fixed it by creating a session. You fixed the NoCredentialsError problem by ... supplying credentials. Specifically those associated with the AWS profile contained in `aws_account`.

Comment: OK gotcha. Thanks.